# Make marker with custom text on google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an Android Application where I'm using Google Map API v2.
I need to show Image & TextView on a map with custom markers.

Please refer to the attached image for better understanding:

[image]